# Will spiral galaxies collapse when expansion of the universe isolates them from the rest of the universe?

Tags: angular-momentum, space-expansion, dark-matter, galaxies, dark-energy

If a galaxy gets isolated when the speed of the expansion of the universe exceeds the speed of light, will it collapse? The rotation of a spiral galaxy prevents it from collapsing due to gravity. So if rotating reference frame depends on inertial reference frame, and for a galaxy the other galaxies define this inertial reference frame, wouldn't a galaxy's rotation stop (in it's new local inertial reference frame) when it gets completely isolated from other galaxies (since no information is transferred between them)? Could this apparent loss of rotational energy explain dark energy (and dark matter)?

Comment: This question seems slightly confused and I find it a bit difficult to understand properly what you're asking as there are a few different questions mixed in together. For one, dark energy *is* the reason for accelerated expansion of the universe. Also the rate of expansion is speed *per unit distance*: it doesn't make sense just to say the expansion exceeds the speed of light without specifying over what distance. To address the question in the title, I'm not sure what relation you think there is between the stability of a spiral galaxy and the rest of the universe?

Comment: @MPT17191 "...for a galaxy the other galaxies define this inertial reference frame..." This sounds like you might thinking of some version of Mach's principle, but that's not how it works in general relativity. In general relativity, inertial frames are defined locally by the metric field, and a galaxy can be rotating in an absolute sense even if it is the only matter in the whole universe. In general relativity, the metric field is present even if matter is absent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if rotating reference frame depends on inertial reference frame, and for a galaxy the other galaxies define this inertial reference frame, wouldn't a galaxy's rotation stop [...] when it gets completely isolated from other galaxies [...]?

As Chiral Anomaly said in a comment, it sounds like you're thinking of Mach's principle. Einstein liked Mach's principle and wanted it to be instantiated in general relativity, but the extent to which GR really follows Mach's principle is debatable. The easy answer to your question is that rotation is absolute in GR, even if there are no other galaxies around.

But I think there may be a Machian way of looking at this.

When matter collapses into a black hole, light (and in theory gravitational waves) from the collapsing matter gets exponentially redshifted and very quickly becomes undetectable, i.e. black. But the gravitational and electromagnetic fields don't go to zero: they remain at full strength forever. They're sometimes called "frozen fields".

The future runaway-expansion phase of the standard cosmological model (called de Sitter space) has a cosmological horizon that looks something like a black hole turned inside out. It's gravitationally attractive like a black hole, and all of the other galaxies eventually fall into it, whereupon light (and in theory gravitational waves) from them redshifts into undetectability. But if you throw an object with electric charge through the horizon, the horizon retains that charge, and though I've never thought about it before, if you toss in matter with significant angular momentum, the horizon ought to retain that angular momentum too. That would make it something like a Kerr (rotating) black hole turned inside out, and like a Kerr black hole it ought to have a frame dragging effect.

The upshot is that if the rest of the galaxies in the universe had a significant net angular momentum, you would end up with a "rotating de Sitter" universe in which the frame dragging effect of those galaxies was preserved. In the real world, they have almost no net angular momentum and we end up with a more or less nonrotating universe in which the lack of any frame dragging effect is preserved. Either way, you can say that the "standard of rotation" that was set in the past by the other galaxies hangs around as a frozen field even after the galaxies are no longer observable.

> Could this apparent loss of rotational energy explain dark energy (and dark matter)?

I don't think so.

---

Looking for information about "rotating de Sitter space" I found [an answer by A.V.S.](/a/390754) that links a paper, but I haven't looked at it and I don't know whether it's an "inside out Kerr" solution. Kerr-de Sitter spacetimes have been studied and I suppose that if rotation of the cosmological horizon is a thing then it ought to show up there. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.00997) notes that the cosmological horizon has an ergosphere in the Kerr-de Sitter solution, which sounds promising.